# Keyword not supported: 'attachdbfilename' - MDF Database File (C#)

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I trying connect to my `.MDF` file but I am not able to accomplish it. I tried various variations of connection strings but still getting this same error.

This my connection string from app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\iseo-db.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and this is how I call this connection string

```
private string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString();

SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(connection);
```

When every I try execute I get a exception saying

> Keyword not supported: 'attachdbfilename'

I would really appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: `.mdf` is a database file for the **full** SQL Server - **NOT** SQL Server **CE**. And the full SQL Server supports the `AttachDbFileName=` statement **only** in the SQL Server **Express** edition. For SQL Server **CE**, you need to use a `.sdf` database file, and another `providerName` in your connection string, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, SQL-Server CE does not use `mdf` files, rather than `sdf` files. Futhermore you don't have to use the property `AttachDbFilename`, then simply use the property `Data Source=...`.

```
 <add name="DBConnection"
      connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|/iseo-db.sdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Some thing like this should do the trick.

**EDIT**

According to @marc_s, the data provider also has to be changed to: `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0`

Comment: The `providername` is wrong - it would have to be `providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"` for SQL Server CE 4.0

Comment: From what I can tell the OP was using LocalDB not SqlServerCe.4.0.  This answer is completely wrong.

Comment: @Jordan but why is it working than? Please tell me what i should "correct" in the answer.

Comment: @BendEg I'm just saying LocalDB and SqlServer CE are two different things. The latter is deprecated.  LocalDB works with mdf files and it uses System.Data.SqlClient as its provider. OP's original configuration should have worked. Migrating back to a deprecated configuration is not a good idea whether it works or not. Thus, this is not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SqlConnection` if you are using LocalDB.  LocalDB is not SQL Server compact edition. It is the full SQL Server.

Compact edition is deprecated and you shouldn't use it. Per documentation, **you can use LocalDB if you want a "local file" database** just like compact edition.  But it works with the full SQL Server provider. That is why you are getting this exception.

Your configuration is fine. You just have to change you connection creation code to use `SqlConnection` instead of `SqlCeConnection`.

```
private string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
```

I know you have accepted the other answer. I don't care. I just want to warn people against continuing to use SQL Server CE. You will have trouble in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using .mdf file you can't use `SqlCeConnection` instead you should use `SqlConnection` to connect to the database. For that, you need to use `System.Data` and `System.Data.SqlClient`.

```
private string connection ="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\iseo-db.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
```

Make sure that you are not using SqlCe any where in your code.